# Почему не загружается форма Ext js для редактирования записи?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Почему не загружается форма в Ext js для редактирования записи?

```
onUpdDiary: function() {
    var win = Ext.widget('addWindowForm');
    var form = win.down('form');
    var record = form.getRecord();
    var values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values);
},
```

Возникает ошибка:

> TypeError: record is undefined

Comment: Вы уверены что на момент вызова `getRecord()` в `data.Model` есть хотябы один загруженный экземпляр? если его нет то происходит попытка вызвать `set(values)` у  `undefined`.